# Iterating over HashMap values compared to Vec

Tags: collections, hashmap, rust

In the program I'm currently writing (a game engine), I would like an efficient way to map integer values (IDs) to an array of objects. The data structure I see as most fit for this is a [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html), but I would also like to be able to loop over the array of objects.

How much slower is it to iterate through the values of a `HashMap` using:

```
for val in map.values()
```

Compared to having a [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) and iterating over it:

```
for val in vec.iter()
```

and then having another system in place for mapping IDs to different indices of the vector?

Are there any other drawbacks to the `HashMap` approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Iterating over a `HashMap` will be slower, simply because the values are not as tightly packed in the `HashMap`: there are empty slots.

How many empty slots there are will depend on your usage, if you have high peak usage however iterating over a now mostly empty `HashMap` will be quite slower than iterating over a `Vec` which is much more compact.

For this particular usecase I would recommend [`indexmap`](https://crates.io/crates/indexmap) which marries the good characteristics of both `HashMap` and `Vec`:

- the values are accessible by key, with performance similar to `HashMap`,
- the values are kept in a `Vec`, with no interleaving empty slot, so iterating has the same performance as iterating a `Vec`.

Comment: OrderMap seems to do exactly what I need! Thank you!

Comment: (For future references to this solution and about the comment above, `ordermap` later became `indexmap` - the latter is still maintained, the former isn't)